# Grouping dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to python pandas and working with dataframes. Lets say that I have the dataframe shown below :

```
A B C

3 2 3
4 2 4
3 2 1 
5 6 6
```

I want to find how many rows in my dataframe have the same value in the A and B column and for these rows I want to store the C value. So for example in this dataframe, I want to store the 1st and 3rd C value, since the A and B in each of these rows have the same values. Basically I want a way to print something like:
"For A = 3 and B = 2 the possible C values are : 3,1" and find those pairs.
Im following the official pandas documentation but I can't seem to find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I follow but this might get you going:

```
df = DataFrame({"a": [3,4,3,5], "b":[2,2,2,6], "c": [3,4,1,6]})
In [38]: for i, g in df.groupby(("a", "b")):
             print  i, g["c"].values
         ....:
(3, 2) [3 1]
(4, 2) [4]
(5, 6) [6]
```

Comment: Wow this was fast and yes this is what I want. Just one more thing, is it possible to print only those that have more than 2 values for c? I want to hide the a,b combinations that have only one c value.

Comment: off top of head could use: if g["c"].shape[0] > 1: print yada yada

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
In [187]: df
Out[187]: 
   A  B  C
0  3  2  3
1  4  2  4
2  3  2  1
3  5  6  6

In [188]: df[df.groupby(['A', 'B']).transform(np.count_nonzero).C>=2]
Out[188]: 
   A  B  C
0  3  2  3
2  3  2  1
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`unique` SeriesGroupBy method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html):

```
In [11]: df.groupby(["A", "B"])["C"].unique()
Out[11]:
A  B
3  2    [3, 1]
4  2       [4]
5  6       [6]
Name: C, dtype: object
```

*See also [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) to get the number of unique elements.*